# When is a setter called for custom elements?

Tags: javascript, class, getter-setter

Context: I am trying to understand how [custom cards work in Home Assistant](https://developers.home-assistant.io/docs/en/lovelace_custom_card.html) (the specificities of Home Assistant do not matter for the general question)

The key step is the creation of a [custom element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements), with a setter:

```
class ContentCardExample extends HTMLElement {
  set hass(hass) {
    // when is that part called?
  }
}

customElements.define('content-card-example', ContentCardExample);
```

As much as I understand `constructor()` in the docs, I have a hard time making sense of the `set`.

- In the example above, when would it be actually called?
- How is this related to the variable `hass` (this is an object which is modified in the course of the life of the app - I am asking the question in the general sense of `set somevariable(someparameter) { ... }`, not specifically for Home Assistant)?

Comment: @trincot: I understand that this is the case for setters, in general. But for a HTML custom element? (what is `instance` there?)

Comment: `instance` is the return value of, say, `document.querySelector("content-card-example")` https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/7ynvu0r8/ (I cannot confirm Jai's claim that setting an attribute calls the setter btw.)

Comment: @ChrisG: I understand, thank you. Would you mind turning this into an answer so that I can accept it as it completely answers the question?